# Find metadata URL from EVM bytecode

Tags: solidity, erc-20, bytecode, compilation, swarm

Currently, I am looking for a way to extract the `metadata.json` file URL from the ethereum bytecode. I have referred to [this doc](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.13/metadata.html#encoding-of-the-metadata-hash-in-the-bytecode) and figured out that metadata mapping is stored CBOR-encoded manner. Hence, I used [CBOR parser](https://pypi.org/project/cbor2/) to decode it. Please find the below example.

**Bytecode:**

```
0x60806040526004361061002d5760003560e01c8063893d20e81461011c578063cf6cbb3d1461017357610117565b36610117576000803690501461004257600080fd5b6000809054906101000a900473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff166108fc349081150290604051600060405180830381858888f19350505050158015610
0a9573d6000803e3d6000fd5b507f6643d795ec4836e9ebd83ebe59402e7510c7fef7c2d84e7eee10ec77898e1d4a3334604051808373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1681526020018281526020019250505060405180910390a1005b600080fd5b34801561012857600080fd5b506101316101ce565b604051808273fffffffff
fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200191505060405180910390f35b34801561017f57600080fd5b506101cc6004803603604081101561019657600080fd5b81019080803573ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff169060200190929190803590602001909291905050506101f7565b005b60008060009054906101000a9
00473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16905090565b6000809054906101000a900473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff163373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff161461025057600080fd5b60008290508073ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1663a9059cbb60008090549061010
00a900473ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16846040518363ffffffff1660e01b8152600401808373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff1673ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff16815260200182815260200192505050600060405180830381600087803b1580156102fd57600080fd5b505af1158015610311573d6000803e3d6000fd5b5050505060003d6
000811461032d576020811461033757600080fd5b6000199150610343565b60206000803e60005191505b508061034e57600080fd5b5050505056fea264697066735822122063fe8f2fa2dbda25d02e48cffe12a007baade89f2491b12f9c259644aa435b3464736f6c63430006080033
```

**Metadata Hash of above bytecode (starting from 0xa264):**

```
a264697066735822122063fe8f2fa2dbda25d02e48cffe12a007baade89f2491b12f9c259644aa435b3464736f6c63430006080033
```

**User CBOR parser to decode:**

```
echo a2646.....> | xxd -r -ps | python3 -m cbor2.tool --pretty

{
    "ipfs": "\u0012 c\\xfe\\x8f/\\xa2\\xdb\\xda%\\xd0.H\\xcf\\xfe\u0012\\xa0\u0007\\xba\\xad\\xe8\\x9f$\\x91\\xb1/\\x9c%\\x96D\\xaaC[4",
    "solc": "\u0000\u0006\b"
}
```

As in the above result, the CBOR parser still gives a Unicode string for IPFS and SOLC values. Is there any approach or method to derive the IPFS **metadata.json** file path from this result? My ultimate goal is to get the contract ABI/metadata from the EVM bytecode.

Please advise me if I am following the wrong way.